# could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout

Tags: scala, akka

I have this code, where I am making an ask request in Scala:

```
someActorRef ? SomeMessage()
```

However, I'm getting this message:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout
```

I also tried this:

```
Await.ready(someActorRef ? SomeMessage(), Duration("3 seconds")).asInstanceOf[String]
```

But I get the same message.

Anyway, I don't want to block. I want to get a `Future` and then later on give it an `onComplete` callback.

Can I ask for a message from another actor without blocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ask` needs an implicit `Timeout`, after which it will just fail the Future with a `TimeoutException`.

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val f = someActorRef ? SomeMessage()
```

Note that nothing will block for those 5 seconds, the `ask` pattern is fully async/non-blocking. It will give you back a `Future`, on which you can block (NOT RECOMMENDED) or attach a callback (as you wish)

```
f.onComplete(doSomething(_))
```

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors).

Answer (score 0):

You can. But don't use `ask`. Just `pipe` result to the sender. E.g. let's say this is an actor which performs long running task and returns a future:

```
class LongRunningTaskPerformer extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case PerformTask => someLongRunningTask() pipeTo sender()
  }
}

class QueryPerformer extends Actor {

  val longRunningTaskPerformer = context.actorOf(LongRunningTaskPerformer.props())  

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TriggerLongRunningTask => longRunningTaskPerformer ! PerformTask
    case result @ Result         => // do something with your result
  }
}
```

In this case, I'm sending a message `PerformTask` to `LongRunningTaskPerformer` actor. When the future is being completed, result will be sent to my `QueryPerformer`. No blocking. Easy.